# asynctask stops main thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app i get weather info from internet in asynctask, but sometimes server is a bit laggy, and i want to make up to 10 requests (if previous was unsuccesful) with 10 second waiting between requests.  But when i make my asynctask wait 10 sec.(modeling not responding server), main thread(user interface) freezes until asynctask finishes it's job(make 10 rounds of requests).

here is the code where i make and execute asynctask

```
WeatherGetter wg = new WeatherGetter();
    wg.execute(url);
    try {
        weather = wg.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and this is where i make it wait

```
if (cod != 200) {
            synchronized (WeatherGetter.this) {
                try {
                    WeatherGetter.this.wait(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting a lock on WeatherGetter before waiting for 10 seconds? You should be notifying your activity that you have the data in onPostExecute.

Comment: Can you please post the whole code? This single part is not helping us

Comment: In weather getter are you doing an http request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

do not wait the thread

call same function recursively if code!=200 like this

```
private void loadWhetherData(final int count) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                WeatherGetter wg = new WeatherGetter();
                wg.execute(url);
                try {
                    weather = wg.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (cod != 200 && count<10) {
                    loadWhetherData(++count);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

    }
```

**Call**

This method will calls 10 times until not suceess

```
loadWhetherData(1);
```

Comment: Did you forget to add .execute() ?

Comment: So i should make another async in my async?

Comment: No no I just given a meta-fore. Just put your asynctask in a method like I put and call it recursively until you get code==200 and count<10

Comment: In your code as i see method will be called 10 times one after another, but i need them to be called with 10 sec pause